# wrapping child node content in xquery

Tags: xquery

I have what I hope is a really simple question, but I'm a novice at xquery and I can't make this work:

I have the following bit of xml:

```
<collation>1<num>12</num> 2<num>12</num> ||
                    I<num>8</num>-V<num>8</num>, 1 flyleaf</collation>
```

That I need to transform so that becomes the content of a new node, like so:

```
<note displayLabel="Collation: Notes">1(12) 2(12) || I(8)-V(8), 1 flyleaf<note>
```

I am using the following xquery code to attempt to do this:

```
<note displayLabel="Collation:Notes">{for $t in doc("collation.xml")//collation,
$h in distinct-values($t)  
return
????
</note>
```

The problem is that I can either display all of the content (so without the parentheses) using data($t), or I can display just the things I want to be in parentheses (the information in the  tags) using data($t/num) but I can't figure out how to display both with the items in  tags wrapped in parentheses.  I'm sure it's a really simple answer but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good job for recursion:

```
declare function local:render(
  $n as node()
) as node()?
{
  typeswitch($n)
    case element(num) return text{concat('(', $n, ')')}
    case element(collation) return 
      <note displayLabel="Collation: Notes">{
        for $n in $n/node()
      return local:render($n)
      }</note>
    case element() return element { node-name($n) } {
      for $n in $n/node()
      return local:render($n)
    }
    default return $n
};

local:render(
<collation>1<num>12</num> 2<num>12</num> || I<num>8</num>-V<num>8</num>, 1 flyleaf</collation>)
```

`=>`

```
<note displayLabel="Collation: Notes">1(12) 2(12) || I(8)-V(8), 1 flyleaf</note>
```